# Fractional power of self adjoint operators.

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to know that $$\langle T^*Tz, z\rangle  = \langle(T^*T)^{\frac {1}{2}}z, (T^*T)^{\frac {1}{2}}z\rangle $$ holds or not? What is the meaning of $$(T^*T)^{\frac{1}{2 }} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that $z \in H$, where $H$ is a Hilbert space and $T$ is a bounded operator on $H$. It is a well-known result that a positive bounded operator $S$ has a unique positive square root, i.e., there is a unique positive operator $S^{1/2}$ that satisfies $(S^{1/2})^2 = S$. Note that $T^* T$ is positive since $\langle T^* T x, x \rangle = \langle T x, T x \rangle = \| T x \|^2 \geq 0$. So $T^* T$ has a unique positive square root $(T^* T)^{1/2}$. Since positive operators are self-adjoint it follows that
$$
\langle T^* T x, y \rangle = \langle ((T^* T)^{1/2})^2 x, y \rangle = \langle (T^* T)^{1/2} x, (T^* T)^{1/2} y \rangle
$$
for all $x, y \in H$.

Comment: What about $(T^*T)^{\mu} $ for any $\mu \gt 0$

Comment: Since the function $f(x) = x^\mu$ is continuous on the spectrum of a positive operator, $(T^* T)^\mu$ also makes sense. You should take a look at the continuous functional calculus for normal operators, which tells you what is meant by expressions like $f(A)$ where $f$ is a continuous function on the spectrum of $A$, a normal operator.